# How do you fix infinite redirects to a Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a Servlet mapped as follows:

```
@WebServlet("/test/*")
```

So that everything accessing `localhost:8080/test/1` or `localhost:8080/test/99` is handled in the same Servlet and forward them to `localhost:8080/test/1/test.html`

The problem is that - my forwarding is falling under the same wildcard rule which is `test/*` - and is causing an infinite loop.

I've tried to fix this with no luck. I've been thinking of adding some kind of counter to keep track of how many times the Servlet has been called, but that would only limit me and create another problem if I want to reuse the Servlet properly.

All help is appreciated since I've been stuck with this the whole day. Thank you thank you thank you!

```
@WebServlet("/test/*")
public class WildcardTest extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println(request.getRequestURL());
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("test.html");
            view.forward(request, response);    
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Resolution:
I used the WEB-INF directory to store your html views. You can forward there without hitting any servlet mappings. I thought this would solve it but it still gives me the same problem.

```
 RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/login.html");
```

Output when requesting http://localhost:8080/test/test:

```
2016-05-15T21:12:37.798+0200|Info: http://localhost:8080/test/test
2016-05-15T21:12:37.798+0200|Info: http://localhost:8080/test/WEB-INF/views/login.html
2016-05-15T21:12:37.798+0200|Info: http://localhost:8080/test/WEB-INF/views/WEB-INF/views/login.html
2016-05-15T21:12:37.798+0200|Info: http://localhost:8080/test/WEB-INF/views/WEB-INF/views/WEB-INF/views/login.html
2016-05-15T21:12:37.798+0200|Info: http://localhost:8080/test/WEB-INF/views/WEB-INF/views/WEB-INF/views/WEB-INF/views/login.html
```

Comment: Since you have mapped "/test/*", everything that matches to "/teste/*" will be handled by your Servlet, no matter whether it's a /test/a/b/c/d/e/f/g or everything else. Thats why you have a redirect loop. You can change your mapping or redirect your request to somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WEB-INF` directory to store your html views. You can forward there without hitting any servlet mappings.

Comment: You have to consider that if you use /WEB-INF/ to store you HTML you won't be able to access them externally.

Comment: @Jaumzera That's usually considered a good thing, especially when you involve JSPs.

Comment: Hi, I did as you said but it still gives me infinite loops. See my updated post please. @Kayaman

Comment: Redirect to `/WEB-INF/views/login.html`. You need the first slash to avoid having a relative (to the servlet) path.